# SQL - TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT to another field

Tags: sql, timestamp

`TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

I have got this line working, but is there a simple to set the Default value to another field, a pre-entered date.

Many Thanks for your replies

Comment: What SQL dialect? mysql/sql server/???

Answer (score 0):

I would use a trigger on Insert.

Just check to see if a value has been assigned, and if not, go grab the correct one and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Make a trigger on insert and update that updates the column with the current timestmap.

reference:
[Sql server on update set current timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594567/sql-server-on-update-set-current-timestamp)