# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in mssql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Here i am trying to use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in mssql.
Here getdate() is available.How can i rewrite with current-date with updated date automatically in sql.

Code I am trying to update:

```
  CREATE TABLE XXXXX
    ( fid int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     Name varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    status varchar(4) DEFAULT 'yes',
     fdate timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  
 ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRIMARY KEY (fid) 
    )
```

Comment: could you post Some sample code on what you  are trying

Comment: CREATE TABLE XXXXX(
 fid int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 Name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 status varchar(4) DEFAULT 'yes',
 fdate timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (fid)
)

Comment: here i am trying to convert this query into sql,but on update is not available in sql right?

Comment: what does on update do in other rdbms ?

Comment: I would suggest to create trigger when updating any row in this table an update date field

Comment: It will update existing date with new date.

Comment: There's no `ON UPDATE .....` clause in SQL Server - if you want to update the column's value in case the row was updated, you need an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger on that table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql server on update set current timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594567/sql-server-on-update-set-current-timestamp)

Answer (score 2):

Create database

```
 CREATE TABLE XXXXX
( 
    fid int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    status varchar(4) DEFAULT 'yes',
    fdate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT getdate() 
)
```

Create trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER Update_fdate
   ON  XXXXX
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE XXXXX
    SET [fdate] = GETDATE()
    WHERE fid IN (SELECT fid FROM Inserted)
END
```

Now it will be updated if someone update it...

If you want to be null just change to NULL and remove the DEFAULT value