# How do I properly use ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP when creating table column?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, triggers

I'm brand new to SQL and I saw that when creating a table with columns I can automatically have a column updated to the current timestamp whenever the column is updated (which is exactly what I want) with the following :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Foo (
  Symbol CHAR(5),
  LastUpdated DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

So, according to my understanding, when I insert a symbol into this table, for example 'Baz', it should create the following entry in the table:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Symbol       |    LastUpdated   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Baz         |  <current time>  |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

And if I update the symbol from 'Baz' to say 'Qux', the LastUpdated column for that row should be changed to whatever the new current datetime is. However, when I run that query within python using the sqlite3 module I get the following error: `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "ON": syntax error`. Here is what the code looks like in Python:

```
self.__conn = sqlite3.connect(database_path)
self.__cursor = self.__conn.cursor()
self.__cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EQData (
                         Symbol CHAR(5),
                         LastUpdated DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)""")
```

I have tried messing around with that column definition a little and I found that if I remove the `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` part so it is just `LastUpdated DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` the query will execute just fine, but the problem is that I still want it to update its LastUpdated column automatically whenever that row is updated. I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479335/current-timestamp-on-update-current-timestamp-in-mssql) that I can use some sort of code that looks like an event is triggered that will update a column when my row when is updated, but I'm not really sure why it works or why I should use that over the piece of code I want to work. Ideally, I would just like the `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` part to work somehow instead of adding the code offered by that user on the other StackOverflow question.

So I have two questions really:

1. Why do I receive an error with the ON UPDATE part despite it being copy/pasted from a source?
2. How do I properly get a row to automatically update it's LastUpdated column whenever the row is updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, unlike MySQL, SQLite does not support the `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` syntax (I am unsure that any other database that MySQL actually offers that feature).

One way to work around this is to use a trigger. Assuming that the primary key of your table is `id`, that would be:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trg_LastUpdated
AFTER UPDATE ON Foo
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Foo SET LastUpdated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id = OLD.id;
END
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=53094ceee0fec564b170e21a7bab9c83)**

Comment: Thanks for the quick response man, is there any way to check if I already have this trigger created so I don't keep re-adding it to my DB? Or is this something I don't have to worry about? My worry is that if this statement is executed multiple times that it will create duplicate triggers that all do the same thing which I'm assuming would create a performance issue. Another question too is, will your SQL statement update the LastUpdated columns on all the rows or just the one that was changed?

Comment: @DomStepek: (1) you can query catalog view `sqlite_master` to list al existing triggers, like `select * from sqlite_master where type = 'trigger';`. (2) this only updates the row that was just updated (provided that you have a primary key, as explained in my answer).